# Cordova IOS/Android screen display with notch and soft menu

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios, cordova-android

Is there a method of working with status bars and navigation bars correctly?

I have a cordova app for both IOS and Android, I know IOS exposes the env(safe-area-inset-top)/const(safe-area-inset-top) depending on the ios version but I cant find anything like this for android.

I want to sit the top of my app just below the status bar instead of the status bar over laying the app. I know I can do padding but i would need to know the height of the status bar to start with.

I'm also looking to adjust the app to cater for soft navigation (samsung phone), i have bottom naviaction within the app but when entering in text the soft keyboard appears and when it's removed it leaves the soft naviaction in place which then partly covers my navigation.

I have viewport set to:

and have set:
window.addEventListener("resize", (e){}) - this does not fire.

any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDVWKWebview for the iOS versions you can set this globally at the CDVWKWebViewEngine.m file (inside -(void)pluginInitialize method, line ~271).

```
    [wkWebView.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentAlways];
```

So you can easily keep writing a single CSS for iOS and Android versions.

P.s> The downside of this solution is that you will have this specific manual modification in the iOS generated project.